# Relatively small social networking web sites?

Tags: webapp-rec

Do you know any social networking web sites for specific universities only?

For example [hoccam](http://web.archive.org/web/20060402204107/http://hoccam.com/) dot com was a social networking web site for [METU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_East_Technical_University).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of universities that run social network sites based on Elgg. You can find some of them on the list here. [Sites powered by Elgg](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Sites_powered_by_Elgg)

Others, such as the University of Mary Washington and University of Lincoln are using Buddypress.

[Saint Augustine's College](http://saintaug.ning.com/) uses Ning and Arizona State has a network called [Is Talking](http://www.asuistalking.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify if price was an option, so you could try [Ning](http://www.ning.com)

Comment: I'm not looking for a software.

Comment: It's not software. It's a hosted site. You create your own social network and they host it using their own software.

Comment: The OP is looking for examples what Facebook was before it went public: closed university-specific social networking sites ("web sites for specific universities only") I imagine...

Comment: Can you not create a network in Ning and then lock it down?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.theflowr.com

it's a Social Network like-Facebook - there is a FREE package, but also some of them are paid. Depending on what you want / need.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [BuddyPress](http://buddypress.org/) (a wordpress plugin), you could either install it in your host or use a web host (there aren't many, but there's [BuddyGrid](http://buddygrid.net/))

Comment: I'm not looking for a software.